# In Y86, what happened when you have more than 6 function parameters?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, calling-convention, y86

Consider this function in c:
long arithEx(long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long);

```
long main()
{

long a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,w;
a=100;
b=12345;
c=98765;
d=23;
e=25;
f=27;
g=29;
h=31;
w=arithEx(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h);
w++;
return w;

}
```

In X-86, the assembly code looks like this:

```
   main:
subq  $24, %rsp
movq  $31, 8(%rsp)
movq  $29, (%rsp)
movq$27, %r9
movq$25, %r8
movq$23, %rcx
movq$98765, %rdx
movq$12345, %rsi
movq$100, %rdi
call  arithEx
addq  $1, %rax
addq  $24, %rsp
ret
```

This makes sense to me since X-86 and Y-86 only have 6 registers to receive function arguments. And For X-86, since it supports immediate to memory addressing mode, we can just store the rest of the parameters to memory.

However, for Y-86, we don't have an instruction that can move an immediate to memory, so where should the rest of the parameters go?

Comment: Never dealt with y86 but this kind of things is mandated by the ABI. Normally once the regs are all used the arguments are pushed on the stack. I can't see why that shouldn't be the case for y86.

Comment: See in X86, the movq can support moving an immediate (i.e a constant) to memory. But for Y-86, there is no such instruction.

Comment: But what about `push`?

Comment: Move the immediate into a register and then store the register to memory? This is just programming. Finding a way to do what you want to do with the tools you have. Sometimes you need to combine multiple tools.